# Can i use underscore.js in the javascript with pdfreactor?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf-reactor

I am trying to build a prototype with pdfreactor. Can i use underscore templates to render my html content? 
If not.. Is there an alternative?

Comment: dont downvote without giving a proper reason!!!

Comment: Why don't you just try it? If it works the answer is "yes". If it doesn't then either it does not work or you did something wrong, in which case you can ask here, with your code, how to solve that problem.

Comment: Okay.. I did try.. It is not detecting underscore.js.. Is there an other alternative to use template, so i can build dynamic html content

Comment: Don't ask rubbish questions if you are so concerned about downvotes then.  Do you seriously expect a one line question to be received with cheers and applause? Your question is also extremely lazy - just try it yourself and see.   And questions asking for recommendations are not even allowed here.  So there are many many very good reasons to down vote you and close this.  You need to try significantly harder in the future if you want to be able to continue asking questions here.

Comment: @JK. And you downvote my answer because don't like the question?

Answer (score 0):

Have you done as it says in the JavaScript section in the [manual](http://www.pdfreactor.com/product/doc_html/index.html#JavaScript)? It says you must enable JavaScript, like this:

```
pdfReactor.setJavaScriptMode(PDFreactor.JAVASCRIPT_MODE_ENABLED);
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, underscore.js should work in PDFreactor. As Björn wrote in his answer you MUST explicitly enable JavaScript. PDFreactor does not process JavaScript by default.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10596912)

Comment: @zev-spitz What's the problem? The original question was "Can i use underscore.js in the javascript with pdfreactor?". I answered: "Yes". How does this "not provide an answer to the question" as you wrote?

Comment: I should have been more careful with the automated message. Your answer adds nothing to Björn's answer, and was added more than 6 months after his.